# how to add ellipsis to pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, ellipse

I need help adding an ellipsis to my pagination script. I can't find anything simple on Google. So that's why I ask on here. Thank you!!! Here is the code;

```
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
   $pageno = $_GET['p'];
} else {
   $pageno = 1;
} // if
$query = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM m3_musicblog");
$query_data = mysql_fetch_row($query);
$numrows = $query_data[0];
$rows_per_page = 4;
$lastpage      = ceil($numrows/$rows_per_page);
$pageno = (int)$pageno;
if ($pageno > $lastpage) {
   $pageno = $lastpage;
} // if
if ($pageno < 1) {
   $pageno = 1;
} // if
$limit = 'ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ' .($pageno - 1) * $rows_per_page .',' .$rows_per_page;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM m3_musicblog $limit");
if ($pageno == 1) {
   echo "<a>««</a> <a>«</a> ";
} else {
   echo " <a href='music-news?p=1'>««</a> ";
   $prevpage = $pageno-1;
   echo " <a href='music-news?p=$prevpage'>«</a> ";
} // if

for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $lastpage; $page_number++)
if($page_number == $pageno) {
echo "<span class='current'>$pageno</span>";
}
else {
echo "<a href='music-news?p=$page_number' class='page' title='$page_number'>$page_number</a>";
}

if ($pageno == $lastpage) {
   echo " <a>»</a> <a>»»</a> ";
} else {
   $nextpage = $pageno+1;
   echo " <a href='music-news?p=$nextpage'>»</a> ";
   echo " <a href='music-news?p=$lastpage'>»»</a> ";
} // if
```

Comment: Do you mean an ellipsis in the bottom links («« « 1 2 ... 5 6 7 ... 102 103 » »») ?

Comment: An Ellipsis is not three dots but `…`. As HTML Entity it is `&hellip;`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$printed_ellipsis = false;
for($page_number = 1; $page_number <= $lastpage; $page_number++) {
    if ($page_number > 4 && !$printed_ellipsis) {
        echo "&hellip;" // horizontal ellipsis character
        $page_number = max(0, $lastpage - 3);
        $printed_ellipsis = true;
    }
    if($page_number == $pageno) {
        echo "<span class='current'>$pageno</span>";
    }else{
        echo "<a href='music-news?p=$page_number' class='page' title='$page_number'>$page_number</a>";
    }
}
```

Sorry if my PHP is a bit off (it's been a while) but you should be able to get the idea of what this code does.

Comment: okay, that worked very well but when i get to fourth page 5 6 7 not showing

Comment: Could you post the output you get, and the output you want instead?